# How to count up with jQuery triggered on scroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll, count

Hi I'm trying to build a counter that counts up when the object is scrolled to. It works on the scroll but then refreshed when you scroll again. The default interval is set to 1.

**How do I have it count only once and then stop?**

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    /* Count Up Numbers on Scroll */
    $('.count-up').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).countTo(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of a "flag" or a trigger, you trigger it after the scroll happens for the first time, and once it triggered you won't count again, something like:

```js
var countIt = true;

$(window).scroll( function(){
    /* Count Up Numbers on Scroll */
    $('.count-up').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, and countIt is true
           thenfade it in        
        */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object && countIt ){

            $(this).countTo(); 
          
            /* set countIt flag to false so that it won't play it again
               as this will be false, the above condition won't met anymore
            */
            countIt = false;
        }
    });
});
```